# React + D3 Force Layout: new Links have undefined positions

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, d3.js, force-layout

I believe I've followed the general update pattern on new React Props. D3 does the data calculation and rendering when new props are received, so that React does not have to render every tick.

D3 works well with a static layout. But when I receive new nodes and links at shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) function, the nodes lack the following attributes:

- index - the zero-based index of the node within the nodes array.
- x - the x-coordinate of the current node position.
- y - the y-coordinate of the current node position.

As a result, all new nodes have `<g tranform=translate(undefined, undefined)/>` and are clustered at the left top corner.

The way I update the props are by pushing new objects to the nodes array and links array. I don't understand why D3 doesn't assign d.x and d.y as it did for the initial setup at componentDidMount(). I have been struggling with this problem for days. Hope someone can help me out here.

Here is the ForceLayout.jsx:

```
//React for structure - D3 for data calculation - D3 for rendering

import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

export default class ForceLayout extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){ //only find the ref graph after rendering
    const nodes = this.props.nodes;
    const links = this.props.links;
    const width = this.props.width;
    const height = this.props.height;

    this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(50))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-120))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    this.graph = d3.select(this.refs.graph);

    this.svg = d3.select('svg');
    this.svg.call(d3.zoom().on(
      "zoom", () => {
        this.graph.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      })
    );

    var node = this.graph.selectAll('.node')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(enterNode);

    var link = this.graph.selectAll('.link')
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .call(enterLink);

    this.simulation.on('tick', () => {
      this.graph.call(updateGraph);
    });
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    //only allow d3 to re-render if the nodes and links props are different
    if(nextProps.nodes !== this.props.nodes || nextProps.links !== this.props.links){
      console.log('should only appear when updating graph');

      this.simulation.stop();
      this.graph = d3.select(this.refs.graph);

      var d3Nodes = this.graph.selectAll('.node')
        .data(nextProps.nodes);
      d3Nodes
        .enter() 
        .append('g')
        .attr("class", "node")
      .call(enterNode);
      d3Nodes.exit().remove(); //get nodes to be removed
      // d3Nodes.call(updateNode);

      var d3Links = this.graph.selectAll('.link')
        .data(nextProps.links);
      d3Links
        .enter()
        .call(enterLink);
      d3Links.exit().remove();
      // d3Links.call(updateLink);

      const newNodes = nextProps.nodes.slice(); //originally Object.assign({}, nextProps.nodes)
      const newLinks = nextProps.links.slice(); //originally Object.assign({}, nextProps.links)
      this.simulation.nodes(newNodes);
      this.simulation.force("link").links(newLinks);

      this.simulation.alpha(1).restart();

      this.simulation.on('tick', () => {
        this.graph.call(updateGraph);
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <svg
        width={this.props.width}
        height={this.props.height}
        style={this.props.style}>
        <g ref='graph' />
      </svg>
    );
    }
  }

  /** d3 functions to manipulate attributes **/
  var enterNode = (selection) => {
    selection.append('circle')
      .attr('r', 10)
      .style('fill', '#888888')
      .style('stroke', '#fff')
      .style('stroke-width', 1.5);

    selection.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d){return 20}) //
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertically centre text regardless of font size
      .text(function(d) { return d.word });
   };

   var enterLink = (selection) => {
      selection.append('line')
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style('stroke', '#999999')
        .style('stroke-opacity', 0.6);
   };

   var updateNode = (selection) => {
       selection.attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
    };

    var updateLink = (selection) => {
      selection.attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);
    };

    var updateGraph = (selection) => {
       selection.selectAll('.node')
          .call(updateNode);
       selection.selectAll('.link')
          .call(updateLink);
    };
```

I've tried pushing new node into the node array at shouldComponentUpdate() function, instead of modifying the arrays in server. But the new node still appears on the left top corner with undefined position. So I am guessing my problem is at shouldComponentUpdate(). Any help is greatly appreciated!!

---

EDIT: found that Object.assign(...) does not return array. Changed it into array.slice() instead. Now all nodes are rendered with a position but not linked at all. Old nodes frayed from original positions as well.

[Here is how it looks when new props go in and shouldComponentUpdate is triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOVNJ.png)

I don't understand why the positions on the links don't correspond to the nodes.

Comment: Just do your true/false check in the shouldComponentUpdate and do the actual modifications in componentWillUpdate. It's hard to tell if this solves anything or what your problem is without debugging, but having wrong lifecycle event do the wrong thing can for sure create funny bugs. Think you need to provide a running snippet to get more detailed help...

Comment: I did the check and it actually modifies at componentWillUpdate. I think I found a problem that caused it, which is I'm feeding in objects instead of arrays in simulation.nodes and simulation.links. Originally, I used Object.assign(...) which returns an object; I've changed it into nextProps.nodes.slice() to create new arrays. So now all nodes have positions, but they are rerendered in an explosion and are not linked at all. I'll post a picture and snippet.

Comment: how have you solved the problem?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem which I found was a combination of bugs:

1. Nodes had no links, or links don't correspond with nodes.

Firstly, my d3 graph and data had different ways to identify nodes - graph looking for index as links when my link data pointed at objects. I resolved this mismatch problem by changing both into id (i.e. looking for a string). This [link](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#link_id) suggested by @thedude pointed me to the right way. Resolving this problem led to the new nodes linked together correctly.

2. The old nodes were still separated, bounced further away, and the old links stay where they were first rendered.

I suspect this is caused by getting graph data from d3, which defined x, y, vx, vy and index properties. So what I did was getting rid of them when I receive currentGraph in server before I update the data.

```
removeD3Extras: function(currentGraph) {
  currentGraph.nodes.forEach(function(d){
    delete d.index;
    delete d.x;
    delete d.y;
    delete d.vx;
    delete d.vy;
  });

  currentGraph.links.forEach(function(d){
    d.source = d.source.id;
    d.target = d.target.id;
    delete d.index;
  });

  return currentGraph;
}
```

That did the trick! Now it behaves how I intend to with no errors on console however I zoom, click and drag.

BUT there is room for improvement:

- the links are on top of nodes
- sometimes nodes are on top of each other during tick, thus requiring dragging and dropping.

Answer (score 1):

the [links](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#link_links) in `forceLink` use by default object references to point to the `source` and `target`.

You don't show how you construct your `links` and `nodes` props, but you can get around it by calling [id](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#link_id) and setting an id accessor to point to your nodes logical id, so assuming your node have an id property this can be written like this:

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id).distance(50))
```

alternatively you could use the node's index as an accessor:

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.index).distance(50))
```

or

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id((d, i) => i).distance(50))
```

-- Edit --

another measure that could help is to merge the properties of current nodes with the new nodes, this will let them retain position:

```
const updatePositions = (newNodes = [], currentNodes = []) => {
  const positionMap = currentNodes.reduce((result, node) => {
    result[node.id] = {
      x: node.x,
      y: node.y,
    };
    return result
  }, {});
  return newNodes.map(node => ({...node, ...positionMap[node.id]}))
}
```

then in your `shouldComponentUpdate` (note, this is not really where this code should live) you could call it like this:

```
var nodes = updatePositions(newProps.nodes, this.simulation.nodes())
```

and use `nodes` instead of `newNodes`.

*Note that this code assumes nodes have a unique id property. Change this to fit your use case*

You should also try adding a `key` function to your selections to identify your nodes and links, e.g.:

```
this.graph.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nextProps.nodes, d => d.id) // again assuming id property
```

Comment: Tried this but did not work. Maybe it's how I construct links and nodes? The way I construct is pushing new nodes and new links into the arrays.

Comment: The strange thing is that it worked when I pushed two nodes and a link on client side, but when I did the same on server side to return a data object for the client side to render, the links have no x1, y1, x2, y2.

Comment: @heidipercyslinky can you share the code that creates the nodes and the links?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I solved the problem myself with help from your link. The id property was part of the culprit.